# List fields missing in Dynamic Content sometimes

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-flow

I'm facing a weird issue. I'm able to access the fields in my list from Dynamic Content section at some places, and not at others. Pls see the screenshot below

I was able to select 'Request State' field in the first condition.
I want to select the same field in the 'Set Variable' activity below, but the field 'Request State' is not even coming in the dynamic content. What could be the reason?

I found the same issue for other few fields as well, not all

btw this 'Request State' is a string type with list of values. So does it make any difference

[image]

Comment: Are your sure Request State is a text column?  Looking at the screenshots, it looks like a multi-select choice or lookup column?

Comment: The Power Automate UI **does** trim the selection of fields based on the type.  For example, if you Initialize a variable as Type = Integer, then when you use a `Set variable` action for that same variable, the Dynamic content box will only show you numeric fields from your Item.  If Request State is a multi-value column, then it will come into your Flow as an array, thus you would not be able to use its value to set a String variable.

Comment: Thankyou. Yes, the field I'm trying in this example is 'LOV' , so I'll go ahead and use Array. One other question, I have a case where in I've to check the value of a people column. I end up in the same issue - how do I assign the value of a 'people' column (meaning the name of the person) - which datatype should i use for the variable

Comment: If you actually need to hold the entire person value, then use a variable of type `object`.  If you are just trying to store the email address or user display name, then you can use a string variable, but then you would need to use the 'Expression' tab of Dynamic Content to retrieve `triggerBody()?['NameOfYourUserField']['Email']`